# Filtering Columns if they contain text from a specific cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new here, so I apologize if this is long-winded/not explained well enough. I have a spreadsheet where data is being filtered from other sheets to combine into one tab. There is a set of data where I use the following formula:

=FILTER(C:C,A:A=F1), where F1 is "June 23: Site 2"

See table below. I would like to point a filter to a given cell, rather than text, to say "Filter this column if it partially contains text from this specific cell."

In column A, where it says "June 23: Site 2" I want the filter to point to a specific cell that says "Site 2." I have a collection of data that is filtered through the phrase "Site 2" without the date included, and this would help automate data from a different source.

[Here is the sheet with a better explanation.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CGq6juXrpdzaWON5TdA3b34PKppJoiEtaQv6TqhiTe4/edit#gid=817876980)

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

| A (Event) | B (Event) | C (Message) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| May 15: Site 1 | Adam | Awesome |
| May 15: Site 1 | Jennifer | Exciting |
| June 23: Site 2 | Tony | Cool |
| June 23: Site 2 | Mark | Tubular |
| August 1: Site 3 | Cathy | Riveting |

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
=FILTER(C2:D6, REGEXMATCH(A2:A6, B8))
```

[image]

but if you want to exclude date you can do:

```
=FILTER(C2:D6, REGEXMATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A6, ": ", ),,2), 
                          INDEX(SPLIT(B8,    ": ", ),,2)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=FILTER(C2:D6, REGEXMATCH(A2:A6, B11))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I did notice that I had a typo in the sheet. I meant to say "How can I "Filter Column C if Column A partially contains text from **bold** `B11`" I accidentally typed B8. The cell I am trying to filter through already has the date removed. Does this change either of the formulas?

Comment: @JeremyMcCloud it does. answer updated